# Showing inequality about number of vertices with ceratin degree for planar graphs

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am currently struggling on showing the following inequality for planar graphs without loops. Let $\delta(G) \geq 3$ and $\tau_i$ be the number of vertices with degree $i$, then:
$$
\tau_5 + 2 \tau_4 + 3 \tau_3 \geq 12 + \tau_7 + 2 \tau_8 + 3 \tau_9 + \ldots + (\Delta-6) \tau_\Delta
$$

So far I know that $\delta(G) \leq 5$ since the graph is planar and without loops. Furhtermore I tried using the inequality $3n-6 \geq m$ for planar graphs or counting the vertices in different ways however I am unable to introduce the scalars $(i-6) \tau_i$ into the equation.

I also tried proving this fact by induction over $\Delta$ however I got stuck at the induction step when trying to reduce it to the base case by merging vertices somehow.

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write the Euler characteristic in terms of these $ \tau_i$? EG $V = \sum \tau_i$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Definetly, that would be $n(G) = \sum_{i=3}^\Delta \tau_i = 2 - l(G) + m(G)$ however as stated in the question I am not sure on how to implement the coefficients (of the $\tau$'s) into this equation.

Comment: For $E$, count the edges in 2 ways. Each edge is connected to 2 vertices. Each vertex is connected to how many other vertices? Hence, how many edge-vertex pairs are there?  $\quad$ For Faces, given that this is a tree, how many faces are there?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are getting at. Each vertex $x$ ist connected to $d(x)$ many other vertices. There are $2m(G)$ edge-vertex pairs (I know that $2m(G) = \sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v)$). If the graph was a tree there would only be one face. However I still don't see what role the scalars for the $\tau$'s play here to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments by Calvin Lin I was able to find the following solution:

With the handshaking lemma we get that:
$$
2m(G) = \sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v)
$$
Furthermore we now surely have
$$
\sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v) = \sum_{i=3} ^\Delta i \tau_i
$$
since in the second sum also the degree of each vertex is counted once.

Furthermore we now have for planar graphs that:
$$
2(3n(G) -6) \geq 2m
$$
Combining these two we get
$$
-12 \geq \sum_{i=3} ^\Delta (i-6) \tau_i
$$
And with this
$$
\tau_5 + 2 \tau_4 +3 \tau_3 \geq 12 + \sum_{i=7}^\Delta (i-6) \tau_i
$$
Which was to be shown.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was going for.